# Создание окна авторизации в приложении

Tags: c#

Нужно создать приложение, которое при запуске отобразит форму входа с логином и паролем (два логина на выбор), а в зависимости от выбранного логина откроет одну из двух других, основных форм и закроется. Можно примерный план действий? У меня не получается.

Answer (score 3):

что именно?

```
var form = Login.Text == "Login1" ? new OneForm() : new AnotherForm()
form.ShowDialog();
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Для WinForms:

```
if(true) 
{
    this.Hide();
    frmMain fm = new frmMain();
    fm.Show();
}
```

Более детальный пример смотрите здесь:

[Simple Windows Form Login Application in C#](http://www.ittutorialswithexample.com/2015/01/simple-windows-form-login-application-in-csharp.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Login1 = "Ad";
            var Pass1 = "1488";
            var Login2 = "Th";
            var Pass2 = "0228";
            var Login3 = "St";
            var Pass3 = "0420";

            if ((textBox1.Text==Login1) && (textBox2.Text==Pass1)) {
                Form2 newForm = new Form2();
                newForm.Show();
            }
            if ((textBox1.Text == Login2) && (textBox2.Text == Pass2))
            {
                Form3 newForm = new Form3();
                newForm.Show();
            }
            if ((textBox1.Text == Login3) && (textBox2.Text == Pass3))
            {
                Form4 newForm = new Form4();
                newForm.Show();
            }
            if ((textBox1.Text != Login3) && (textBox2.Text != Pass3) && (textBox1.Text != Login1) && (textBox2.Text != Pass1) && (textBox1.Text != Login2) && (textBox2.Text != Pass2))
            {
                Form5 newForm = new Form5();
                newForm.Show();
            }
            //else if { ((textBox1.Text == Login2) && (textBox2.Text == Pass2))
            //      Form3.ActiveForm;
            //}
            //else if 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should answer in Russian.